# Grouped Data Endless Scroll ListView Kendo Not working

Tags: listview, kendo-ui, autoscroll

I can't get kendo listview to properly auto scroll when I have grouping.  Change autoscroll to true to see issue below.

I am also having a similar problem with angular.

JSFiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/jcbowyer/ao0xzoaz/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.226/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="view">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-source="groupedData" data-template="my-template" data-header-template="header-template" data-endless-scroll="false"></ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="my-template">
            <h3 class="item-title">#: name #</h3>
             <p class="item-info">#: description #</p>

        </script>
        <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="header-template">
            my group - #: value #

        </script>
        <script>
            var groupedData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
               schema : {total: function (data) {
                 return 5}
             },
              data: [
                { name: "Sashimi Salad", description: "Organic greens topped with market fresh sashimi, wasabi soy vinaigrette.",  letter: "S" },
                { name: "Seaweed Salad", description: "A nice seaweed salad.",  letter: "S" },
            { name: "Edamame", description: "Boiled soy beans with salt.",  letter: "E" },
            { name: "Maguro", description: "Tuna pieces.",  letter: "M" },
            { name: "Tekka Maki", description: "Tuna roll with wasabi.",  letter: "T" },
            { name: "California Rolls", description: "Crab sticks, avocado and cucumber.",  letter: "C" }
              ],
              group: { field: "letter" },
            pageSize: 2
            });

            new kendo.mobile.Application();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Telerik support this grouped data is not a supported configuration when virtual scrolling is enabled.